# How do I use Manipulate on Show to remove/add a group of plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

I want to be able to use Manipulate on Show[plot1,plot2] in order to make groups of plot appear/disappear. I've tried running the code below but the checkmarks doesn't add/remove the visibility of plots.

```
plot1 = Plot[{Cos[x], 2*Cos[x], 1/2*Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"], PlotStyle -> Orange];
plot2 = Plot[{Sin[x], 2*Sin[x], 1/2*Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"], PlotStyle -> Green];
Manipulate[
 Show[plot1, plot2, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[a], Opacity[b]}], {{a, 1, "Cosines"}, {1, 
   0}}, {{b, 1, "Sines"}, {1, 0}}, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
 FrameMargins -> 0]
```

The following produces the combined plot of:
[image: Show Manipulate]

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2467336).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{plot1, plot2, x},
  plot1 = 
   Plot[{Cos[x], 2*Cos[x], 1/2*Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"], 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Orange, Opacity[a]}]]; 
  plot2 = Plot[{Sin[x], 2*Sin[x], 1/2*Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"], 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[{Green, Opacity[b]}]];
  Show[plot1, plot2]
  ],
 {{a, 1, "Cosines"}, {1, 0}},
 {{b, 1, "Sines"}, {1, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Top, FrameMargins -> 0,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Produces the correct result, but in principle using `Opacity` if just hiding/displaying things is needed is not the preferred way.

Comment: @Mathias I agree. But this is not my method. I just fixed the issue with the OP code to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the plots opacity I would rather recommend to exclude/include them in the `Show` command.
Here is a working solution:

First generate the plots

```
plot1 = Plot[{Cos[x], 2*Cos[x], 1/2*Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> Dashed];
plot2 = Plot[{Sin[x], 2*Sin[x], 1/2*Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> Thick];
```

And then use simple `If` to decide if the plot should be shown.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{If[a == 1, plot1, Nothing], If[b == 1, plot2, Nothing]}],
 {{a, 1, "Cosines"}, {1, 0}},
 {{b, 1, "Sines"}, {1, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Top,
 FrameMargins -> 0,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}
]
```

In this case also the `PlotLegend` is displayed or hidden for the choosen plots.[image]